# Add a custom teams template to teams admin center by Graph API or any other way by programmatically

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I know we can create our own or custom teams template in teams admin center. We can create teams based on that template by graph API by passing that created template ID. But is there any way to create template and add to admin center by Graph API or any other way by programmatically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @adminM365 Please go through this [documentation](https://jeffbrown.tech/working-with-microsoft-teams-templates-and-graph-api/).

Comment: Please let us know does that clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no graph API to create template and add to admin center.

we recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.